# how may add a new properties in array objets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mdbtable

***Hi, How may add a new properties in array objets***

*Well what I want to do is I can add a new property so that I can read the template from the* ***MDBTABLE***

**i have the next example**

```js
const instutions = [
  {
    name: 'Malasia',
    direction: 'Asia'
  },
  {
    name: 'New Francia',
    direction: 'paris'
  }
];
```

well now, i would like add new properties and result It would be something like this

```js
const instutions = [
  {
    name: 'Malasia',
    direction: 'Asia',
    buttonAdd: 'Hello world'
  },
  {
    name: 'New Francia',
    direction: 'paris',
    buttonAdd: 'Hello world'
  }
];
```

Well add new properties, object array, you could do something like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a property in many ways. The higher-order function `map` is one of them. See the example.

```js
const institutions = [{name: 'Malasia',direction: 'Asia'},{name: 'New Francia',direction: 'paris'}];
    
institutions.map(el => el.new_property = 'Hello')
    
console.log(institutions)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property to every object of you array by using forEach method

```
instutions.forEach(elem => elem.buttonAdd = "Hello world");
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach